# Missing object in randomForest model when predicting on test dataset

Tags: r, random-forest

Sorry if it was already asked, but I couldn't find it in half an hour of looking, so I would appreciate if you can point me to some direction.

I have a trouble with missing object in the model, while I don't actually use this object when building the model, it's just present in the dataset. (as you can see in the example below).

It is a problem, because I have already trained some rf models, I am loading the models into environment and I am reusing them as they are. The test dataset doesn't contain some variables that are present in dataset upon which the model was built, but they are not used in the model itself!

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)

smp_size <- floor(0.75*nrow(iris))
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(iris)), size = smp_size)

train <- iris[train_ind, ]
test <- iris[-train_ind, ]

test$Sepal.Length <- NULL  # for the sake of example I drop this column

rf_model <- randomForest(Species ~ . - Sepal.Length, # I don't use the column in training model
                         data = train)

rf_prediction <- predict(rf_model, newdata = test)
```

When I try to predict on test dataset, I get an error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

What I hope to achieve, is use the models I have already built, as redoing them without missing variables would be costly.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: The best solution I came to is removing columns from the input dataset in model this way: `rf_model <- randomForest(Species ~ . - Sepal.Length, data = train[,-which(colnames(data) %in% c('Sepal.Length'))]` But this needs to be specified when training the model and not after :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your models are already built. You will want to add missing columns back on to the test set before running the model. Just add the missing columns with a value of 0 as in the following exmaple.

```
library(randomForest)
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

smp_size <- floor(0.75*nrow(iris))
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(iris)), size = smp_size)

train <- iris[train_ind, ]
test <- iris[-train_ind, ]

test$Sepal.Length <- NULL  

rf_model <- randomForest(Species ~ . - Sepal.Length, 
                         data = train)

# adding the missing column to your test set.
missingColumns <- setdiff(colnames(train),colnames(test))
test[,missingColumns] <- 0 



rf_prediction <- predict(rf_model, newdata = test)

rf_prediction

#showing this produce the same results
train2 <- iris[train_ind, ]
test2 <- iris[-train_ind, ]

test2$Sepal.Length <- NULL  
train2$Sepal.Length <- NULL  

rf_model2 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., 
                         data = train2)


rf_prediction2 <- predict(rf_model2, newdata = test2)

rf_prediction2 == rf_prediction
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for the answer, I did it the way you are advising, but I was hoping there would be more elegant solution. Because when I use the exact same formula in gbm model, I don't get any errors, so I thought it would be possible to adjust some setting of the model to ignore the missing columns.

Comment: I made this a bit more generic by showing how to get the missing columns and set them to 0.

Comment: If there won't be a better answer in two days or so, I'll mark your answer as correct and move on :)

Comment: I was surprised by this as well, there is obviously something odd about the implementation in randomForest that looks for ignored features. It may be worth running down or atleast submitting a bug.